# Creating a MongoDB with an array that displays an image based on the db entry

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

I am creating MongoDB with a user schema shown below:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide name'],
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50
    },

    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide email"],
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 50,
        match: [
            /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            'Please provide a valid email',
          ],
          unique: true,
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide password'],
        minlength: 3
    },

    grid: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please see settings to set grid size.'],
        minlength: 1
    },

    squares: {
        type: Array,
        required: [false]
        minlength: 1
    },
});
```

This would ultimately look like this:

```
_id: xxxxxx
name: "Test Name"
email: "test@test.com"
password: "password"
grid: "35"
squares: Array
    0: "someid"
    1: "someotherid"
```

Where the grid is an id that will be handled to display a certain grid size of div elements. 35 would be a 5 x 7 grid and 48 would be a 6 x 8 grid. (There are only two options users can select.) Then with the square array giving the id for the images in each square of the grid.

The problem I am running into is whenever I try to call the grid id, it give me undefined. I can see from the db side, the entries into the database are correct.

What is the best way to get the string that the user has in their entry for grid to ultimately make either a 5 x 7 grid with div elements or 6 x 8 grid? Should I be storing this differently?

I was planning on doing an if function and having it render either grid, but running into it being undefined.